# Apply to function to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="pills">  
        <li id="l1"><a id="link1">Lesson 1</a></li> <hr>
        <li id="l2"><a href="#" >Lesson 2</a></li> <hr>
        <li id="l3"><a href="#" >Lesson 3</a></li> <hr> 
    </ul>
   <div class="span16" id="target">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#l1').click(function(){
    $('#target').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#target').load("lesson/lesson1.html", function(){
                $('#target').fadeIn('slow');

                });
            });

        });
```

I have 5 links within my webpage, I was wondering if there was anyway to make this one piece of code instead of copy + pasting it multiple times.

Comment: Show us the HTML, without it it would be guessing what you are trying to do.

Comment: usually for targeting groups you don't want to use IDs but rather classes or elements. Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Why in the world would you wait for the animation to finish before sending the AJAX request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('a.AjaxLink').click(function(){
    var url = this.href;

    $('#target').fadeOut('fast')
                .load(url, function(){ $(this).stop(true, false).fadeIn('slow'); });
    });

    return false;
});
```

This code handles the click event for all `<a>`s with a class of `AjaxLink`.

In the click handler, it grabs the `href`, fades out your `#target`, and performs the AJAX load.

When the AJAX load finishes, it [stops the animation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) (in case the AJAX was faster than the fade), then fades it back in.

Finally, it tells the browser not to take the default action (navigating to the page) by returning false.

Comment: Alright...could please explain the code? I'm still quite new to javascript.

Comment: @tsand: What don't you understand?

Comment: @tsand I think you need to put `class="AjaxLink"` to every link you want that to happen. Then the function should work for every `<a>` that have the class `AjaxLink`

Comment: @SLaks this.href and a.AjaxLink, I don't quite understand what's going on.

Comment: @tsand: `this` is a raw DOM element.  It has an `href` property that returns value of the `href=""` HTML attribute.  `a.AjaxLink` is a jQuery (or CSS) selector.  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @SLaks Ok I understand it now, but from where does it pull tut/lesson1.html from?

Comment: From the `href="..."`.  You may want to change that to use `data-*` attributes and `$(this).data`.

Comment: @SLaks so the `href="..."` would be <a>?

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` instead of `id`. Select elements using `class`.
Also you can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a new jQuery method. Given this HTML:

```html
<a class="hello" href="#">Hello</a>
<a class="goodbye" href="#">Goodbye</a>

<div id="target"></div>
```

You'd use this code:

```js
jQuery.fn.switchTarget = function( target, href ) {
    var $target = $(target);

    this.bind( 'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $target.fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $target.load( href, function() {
                $target.fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });

    return this;
};

$('.hello').switchTarget( '#target', 'hello.html' );
$('.goodbye').switchTarget( '#target', 'goodbye.html' );
```